# Ember.js dynamic content inside helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, view-helpers

I have this template with a bunch of attributes coming from its view. For all of these attributes, I need to check if they whether they are null or not and show them:

```
...
<div {{bind-attr class=":(foo-class) view.foo::hidden"}}>{{view.foo}}</div>
<div {{bind-attr class=":(bar-class) view.bar::hidden"}}>{{view.bar}}</div>
...
```

To make the template less verbose, I would like to create a helper, let's say `displayAttribute`, that takes the name of the parameter and returns the proper HTML content.

However, I don't know how to build the string to return inside the helper in a way that the bindings are working.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('displayAttribute', function(attr, tag) {
    if (typeof(tag) === 'undefined') {
      tag = 'div';
    }

    // TODO: generate output string

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(output);
});
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inorder to make bindings work, you are required to use `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper`

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('displayAttribute', function(value,options) {
    if (typeof(tag) === 'undefined') {
      tag = 'div';
    }

    // TODO: generate output string

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(output);
}, dependentKeys);
```

Note that it takes 3 params.

```
@param {String} name
@param {Function} function
@param {String} dependentKeys*
```

For more documentation, i suggest to go through following links.

[Ember API Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper)
[Ember Source Code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.5.0/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/ext.js#L221)

### Here is the content from code docs

### Example with options

Like normal handlebars helpers, bound helpers have access to the options
  passed into the helper call.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('repeat', function(value, options) {
    var count = options.hash.count;
    var a = [];
    while(a.length < count) {
        a.push(value);
    }
    return a.join('');
  });
```

This helper could be used in a template as follows:

```
  {{repeat text count=3}}
```

## Example with bound options

Bound hash options are also supported. Example:

```
{{repeat text countBinding="numRepeats"}}
```

In this example, count will be bound to the value of
  the `numRepeats` property on the context. If that property
  changes, the helper will be re-rendered.

## Example with extra dependencies

The `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` method takes a variable length
  third parameter which indicates extra dependencies on the passed in value.
  This allows the handlebars helper to update when these dependencies change.

```
  Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('capitalizeName', function(value) {
    return value.get('name').toUpperCase();
  }, 'name');
```

## Example with multiple bound properties

`Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` supports binding to
  multiple properties, e.g.:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('concatenate', function() {
    var values = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1);
    return values.join('||');
  });
```

Which allows for template syntax such as `{{concatenate prop1 prop2}}` or
  `{{concatenate prop1 prop2 prop3}}`. If any of the properties change,
  the helpr will re-render.  Note that dependency keys cannot be
  using in conjunction with multi-property helpers, since it is ambiguous
  which property the dependent keys would belong to.

Here is the [working jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/diqiy/2/edit) as an example